# Table cells are not passing their IDs into my function's parameters

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, event-handling, event-listener

**My small code**

https://codepen.io/kymed/pen/wxawJX

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm learning javascript right now, beginner web developer. I'm practicing by building a simple tic tac toe app. Each cell in the tic tac toe table has an id from 0 to 8 and when i try to attach that id to a tileSelected() function (for when the tile is clicked), all onclick events for each cell holds the id of the last cell. (JS Code 7 to 9)

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
document.getElementById(i.toString()).onclick = function() { tileSelected(i.toString()); }
}
```

**What I've tried**

I changed up that code many times before to pass the IDs  into that function for the onclick event though it has the same problem everytime

**So what is the bug here? What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've declared your `for` loops, `i` is a global variable. When these loops finish, `i` has a value of 9. It's that value of 9 that's seen when the callback function gets called. If you scope the variable to the loop by using `for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)`, you'll see an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You `i` value is 9 so you tileSelected function call `i.toString()` with so it is always 9.

You can use `this` and pass id. The `this` keyword evaluates to the value of the This Binding of the current execution context

`tileSelected(this.id);`

```js
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  document.getElementById(i.toString()).onclick = function() { tileSelected(this.id); }
}
```